# How to fix react-hooks/exhaustive-deps error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, paging

I met `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` lint error warning. Here is my code

```js
const fetchData = async pageNumber => {
    if (pageNumber > totalPages) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      // ... call api
      const content = response.data.content;
      if (pageNumber === 1) {
        setTotalPages(response.data.totalPages);
        setActivityData(content);
      } else {
        setActivityData([...activityData, ...content]);
      }
      setCurrPage(currPage + 1);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      // ...
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(currPage);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [currPage]);

useEffect(() => {
  setCurrPage(1);
  setActivityData([]);
  setTotalPages(1);
}, [activityStatus]);
```

These functions are designed to display the `activityData` paginatedly.

If I put fetchData in dependencies, it will raise another error saying this function will re-render. I've seen other posts suggesting putting fetchData inside useEffect, but I can't do it in my code.

1. What's wrong with my way of using useEffect?
2. Is there a better way to manage pagination and display it in a flow?

Comment: Your first `useEffect` is sorta fine and the second one isn't. `useEffect` is for syncing React state to something **outside** of React, like `localStorage` or a network request. In the second effect, you're only syncing React states with each other. Try to move that code into the event handler that sets the `activityStatus` state.

And same could go for the first effect, can you move into the event handler where the `currPage` state is changed? See [You Might Not Need An Effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) in the React docs.

Answer (score 0):

I used to put the `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` everywhere, but now I know that it's not (always) the case.

When I see an EsLint error complaining about something, usually I turn on my brain and I'm thinking: *"How can I do it better in order to remove this problem?"*

In your case, you have a `useEffect` that triggers when `currPage` changes. This is causing the loading to become true, gets the content and update the page number. Let's try to refactor it, separating all the things into two important steps:

1. You need to obtain data
2. You set your component

```js
// OUTSIDE COMPONENT
async function getData(pageNumber: number) {
  // Your logic here
  return await fetchDataFromSomewhere();
}

// INSIDE COMPONENT
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); // Not loading yet
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // Empty array to start with
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1); // I'm on page 1 already
  const [maxPages, setMaxPages] = useState(1); // 1 Page so for now 1 page max

  // Every time page changes (so also the first time this will load)
  useEffect(() => {
   setLoading(true);
   getData(currentPage).then((result) => {
     // Ok!
     setData(result);
     if (currentPage === 1) {
       setMaxPages(result.pages);
     }
     setLoading(false);
   }).catch(() => {
     // Oh no! Handle error! And then...
     setLoading(false);
   })
  }, [currentPage]);

  const goToNextPage = () => {
    // Check for max pages
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  }

  const goToPreviousPage = () => {
    // Check for min pages
    setCurrentPage(currentPage -1);
  }

  // Other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your question 1 - question 2 is more opinion-based and more appropriate for a different Stack Exchange (like Code Review).

TL;DR: wrap your function in useCallback.

When you define a function in the body of a component, it will get recreated every time the component is computed for possible re-rendering. For many functions, that's fine; the cost of recreating the function is minimal.

However, everything changes once an effect depends on that function. Since the function is recreated, it fails a referential equality check. This causes the infinite loop:

1. Function is created
2. useEffect fires, since the function has changed
3. Component body re-runs, recreating the function again
4. Loop back to step 1

This is why [useCallback](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) exists. It caches the defined function so that it will only be recreated if one of its dependencies changes. This means the function passes the equality check and won't cause the effect to fire again.

1. Function is created
2. useEffect fires, since the function has changed
3. Component body re-runs, but the function is not recreated
4. useEffect doesn't fire again, loop is prevented

In your code this would look something like:

```js
const fetchData = useCallback(async pageNumber => {
  // ...
}, [
  // eslint will tell you what the function should depend on
]);
```